# How are slow motion Holi scenes shot?

Tags: film-techniques

I always wanted to know how [holi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holi) scenes with slow motion get captured. Is it purely a slow motion or is it CGI or any other technique?

Below are some screenshots to demonstrate the effect:

[image]

[image]

(These pictures may not belong to any movie)

They not only use slow motion for liquid colour but also for powdered colour.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by holli/holi, but as far as I know these usually are not CGI. Of course, this depends on the movie. For smooth recording of this, they use cameras that record with a lot of frames per second.

Comment: @poepje holi is indian festival of colours.

Comment: @poepje, What is " cameras that record with a lot of frames per second."? I did not get it!

Comment: @Mistu4u - movie camera's record a number of still pictures per second, most movie camera's are 24 pictures or frames taken per second.  The Hobbit was recorded at 48 frames per second.  Some camera's used for shots like this can take hundreds of frames per second.  So you can slow it down and it still looks smooth.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These types of shots are achieved using a high-speed camera, as alluded to in the comments preceding your question.

Newer technology has allowed filmmakers to shoot with digital cameras that can record between 2,000 to 5,000 frames per second - subsequently when the film is played back at a standard 24 FPS or 30 FPS the result is super slow-motion.

There are a number of films that utilize this technique, and a handful of TV shows including *Spartacus*, but the best examples of the filming technique can be found on the show *Time Warp*.

Check out this [link to the Time Warp site](http://dsc.discovery.com/tv-shows/other-shows/videos/other-shows-time-warp-videos.htm) for some amazing video examples.